# tinyMCE in WordPress Meta Box - how to enable the kitchen sink?

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I;ve got several TinyMCE boxes in the meta box of my plugin, but for whatever reason, it's the most basic setup possible and there's no button for advanced mode. What I need is the Kitchen Sink enabled when it renders. Is this possible?

Comment: Show one of your meta boxes code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's what I did, including making sure that tinyMCE was forced into the width I wanted, as opposed to what it decided... In the meta box, I had  tags with a class of .custom-editor-container, and the textareas had a class of .custom-editor. So here's the JS:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    skin: 'wp_theme',
    width : 500,
    selector : '.custom-editor'
});
```

That created the WP based editor, but still no kitchen sink. I don't really need kitchen sink, but it would've been nice. One problem this creates is that tinyMCE puts ALL the toolbar items in one row. The only way to enforce the width I needed was a boatload of CSS:

```
.custom-editor-container {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    width: 500px !important;
}
.custom-editor-container .mceEditor,
.custom-editor-container .mceEditor .mceLayout
.custom-editor-container .mceEditor .mceFirst,
.custom-editor-container .mceEditor .mceFirst>div,
.custom-editor-container .mceEditor .mceFirst>div>span{
    width: 490px !important;
}
.custom-editor-container .mceEditor .mceFirst>div>span .mceToolbar{
    display: block !important;
    float: left;
}
.custom-editor {
    border: 0;
    max-width: 490px;
    width: 490px;
}
```

Hope that helps!